# Counter example to "$(P_1...P_{r-1})\cap P_r = \{ e \}$ if $P_i \cap P_j = \{ e \}$ and $P_i$ is normal in $G$"

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, normal-subgroups

Let $G$ be a group, and $P_1, ..., P_r$ its normal subgroups such that $i \neq j \Rightarrow P_i \cap P_j = \{ e \}$.
I need to prove that then

$(P_1...P_{r-1})\cap P_r = \{ e \}$

Edit: the claim is wrong. So I edited the question(instead of showing a proof it now asks of finding a counterexample to the claim).

Comment: I haven't thought through, but here is a warning.  Your claim seems suspicious.  I think it is wrong.

Comment: @Batominovski Thank you. Should I delete the question? Or maybe you'll write and answer and I accept it, so we can "close it"(not in a technical sense, but in a philosophical one). What do you think?

Comment: I put the comment as an answer.  I leave it to you to decide whether to accept the answer or to delete the question.  Both are fine by me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is indeed wrong.  Let $G=(\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z})^2$.  Take $r=3$.  Let $P_1$ be the subgroup generated by $(1,0)$, $P_2$ by $(0,1)$, and $P_3$ by $(1,1)$.